# Is the DXF group code stored in the objects?

Tags: .net, autocad-plugin

I want to understand how the filtering process of objects using `DXF group Code` in AutocCAD works. Is the `DXF group code` stored in the object itself.For example:

Is the `DxfCode.start` tag stored in each `entity` object ? 
Or the `DXF` tagging is just to ease the process of filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually stored, but an entity can be serialized into .dxf or .dwg file format.

During search/select it helps on filtering

Comment: Thanks, so with the help of DXF code, we can describe any objects of Autocad.